# Updating app overwrites URL

Tags: ios, swift, url, video

I am writing an app to save and play videos for an iPhone in Swift 3. When first installed from Xcode the app works, loading, playing, and saving videos. It then continues to work after the app is closed and reopened. When the app is run from Xcode again the videos no longer play. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

This is my save and load functions

```
func saveVideos(){

    NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(videoArray, toFile: filePath)

}
func loadVideos(){

    if let array = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: filePath) as? [Video]{

            videoArray = array

            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }

    }
```

This is the code that opens the url in AVPlayer and plays it

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let video = videoArray[indexPath.row]
    let videoUrl = video.url

    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl)
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        playerViewController.player!.play()
    }
}
```

Each url is wrapped in a custom class called Video which is stored in an array of Videos. The array of videos is stored in the users directory at filePath

Edit:
This is the code for the file

```
var filePath : String  {

    let manager = FileManager.default
    let url = manager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    return (url?.appendingPathComponent("videosFile").path)!
}
```

Comment: Never save a full file path. Calculate a new path each time. This is because an app's sandbox can change.

Comment: @rmaddy the file path is recalculated each time, that code is just not shown here

Comment: You should show the code for how you set `filePath` for both saving and loading videos.